# Passing by reference to n-th element in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pass-by-reference

In C, if we have an array, we can pass it by reference to a function. We can also use simple addition of `(n-1)` to pass the reference starting from `n`-th element of the array like this:

```
char *strArr[5];
char *str1 = "I want that!\n";
char *str2 = "I want this!\n";
char *str3 = "I want those!\n";
char *str4 = "I want these!\n";
char *str5 = "I want them!\n";
strArr[0] = str1;
strArr[1] = str2;
strArr[2] = str3;
strArr[3] = str4;
strArr[4] = str5;
printPartially(strArr + 1, 4); //we can pass like this to start printing from 2nd element

....

void printPartially(char** strArrPart, char size){
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    printf(strArrPart[i]);
}
```

Resulting in these:

```
I want this!
I want those!
I want these!
I want them!

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.006 s
Press any key to continue.
```

In C#, we can also pass reference to an `object` by `ref` (or, `out`). The object includes array, which is the *whole* array (or at least, this is how I suppose it works). But how are we to pass by reference to the `n`-th element of the array such that internal to the function, there is only `string[]` whose elements are one less than the original `string[]` without the need to create new array?

Must we use `unsafe`? I am looking for a solution (if possible) without `unsafe`

Edit:

I understand that we could pass `Array` in C# without `ref` keyword. Perhaps my question sounds quite misleading by mentioning `ref` when we talk about `Array`. The point why I put `ref` there, I should rather put it this way: is the `ref` keyword can be used, say, to pass the reference to `n`-th element of the array as much as C does other than passing reference to any `object` (without mentioning the `n`-th element or something alike)? My apology for any misunderstanding occurs by my question's phrasing.

Comment: You can just pass it the array and the starting index. The code works in `C` as (at least in this case) arrays and pointers are interchangeable. That's not so in `C#` (regardless of how it's implemented under-the-covers). You should treat the array as any other ordered collection.

Comment: @Rob yes, that is possible solution, Sir. And you are right, not that I didn't think of such possibility (referring to passing of the starting index), but I am looking for an alternative for the case such that, if possible, just as we would instinctively see an array should be started from index 0 (like the C example), we could do it like that in the C# function/method also.

Comment: Seems like premature optimization? C# does string interning for literal strings for you so I think it would already be optimized.

Comment: @Rob I mean, after all C# has `ref` `keyword`. I wonder if there is more we can do with it which I probably am not aware of.

Comment: @JesseGood "string interning for literal strings" I am not aware of such feature, Sir. What is it and what does it do?

Comment: @Ian: [From here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) `The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program.` I would suspect what you see in the C code being done under the hood for you in C#.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks, will look into that!

Comment: The `ref` or `out` keywords bear no significance here. Arrays are _always_ reference types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

You won't be able to do it as you do in C in **safe** code.

A C# array (i.e. `string[]`) is derived from abstract type [`Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).
It is not only a simple memory block as it is in **C**.

So you can't send one of it's element's reference and start iterate from there.

---

But there are some solutions which will give you the same taste of course (without *unsafe*):

Like:

- As @Chris mentioned you can use `ArraySegment<T>`.
- As `Array` is also an `IEnumerable<T>` you can use `.Skip` and send the returned value. (but this will give you an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an `Array`). But it will allow you iterate.
- etc...

Comment: I understand that we could do it in C# without `ref` keyword. Perhaps my question misleads some people. Maybe I show rather put it this way: is the `ref` keyword can be used, say to pass the reference to n-th element of the array as much as C does?

Comment: @Ian I edited my answer to fix my misunderstandings.

Answer (score 3):

The "safe" approach would be to pass an [ArraySegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx) struct instead.

You can of course pass a pointer to a character using unsafe c#, but then you need to worry about buffer overruns.

Incidentally, an Array in C# is (usually) allocated on the heap, so passing it normally (without ref) doesn't mean copying the array- it's still a reference that is passed (just a new one).

Comment: Thanks for the link, Sir. Will take a look on that. If you could give a little more explanation on how it works with some code will be best though.

Comment: @Ian you can easily see yourself how it works by looking at source - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/arraysegment.cs,d2e9d465e1639af7 (also there is nothing non-trivial in the code - it is the same as anyone would do to show just view of array - offset of start and boundary check before redirecting index to original array). If you need more explanation - consider asking separate question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for the material. Will check on that!

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is a very common one. The essential point is realizing that "reference types" and "passing by reference" (ref keyboard) are totally independent. In this specific case, since string[] is a reference type (as are all arrays), it means the object is not copied when you pass it around, hence you are always referring to the same object.

Modified Version of C# Code:

```
string[] strArr = new string[5];
strArr[0] = "I want that!\n";
strArr[1] = "I want this!\n";
strArr[2] = "I want those!\n";
strArr[3] = "I want these!\n";
strArr[4] = "I want them!\n";
printPartially(strArr.Skip(1).Take(4).ToArray());

void printPartially(string[] strArr)
{
    foreach (string str in strArr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: But he doesn't want to pass the whole array, he wants to pass a reference to a fixed position of the array.  This doesn't do that.

Comment: You're now not passing a reference to the items in the array, you're copying them to a new array, and thus changes to the copy won't affect the original.

Answer (score 0):

If the method should only read from the array, you can use linq:

```
string[] strings = {"str1", "str2", "str3", ...."str10"};
print(strings.Skip(1).Take(4).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is old, but maybe answer will be useful for someone.
As of C# 7.2 there are much more types to use in that case, ex. [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-2.1) or [Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=netcore-2.1).
They allow exactly for the thing you mentioned in your question (and much more).
[Here's great article about them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx)

Currently, if you want to use them, remeber to add `<LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>` in .csproj file of your project to use C# 7.2 features